# PCIe lanes distribution on in different interface

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

i5 12400f provide up to 20 lanes and compatible chipset like B760 have 14 lane whereas MSI Pro B760M-EDDR4 have 1x16, 1x4 interface.

How these lanes are allocated chipset has only 14 lanes then how many lanes are in x16 interface?

How do these works? How can my graphics card work at full potential because there are only 14 lanes support by chipset?

And this motherboard is a budget one so it can't provide extra lanes to x16.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, processor lanes are separate from the chipset lanes, so the
total number of data-lanes is the sum of both.

Processor lanes are reserved for graphics card x16 slots
and M.2 slots for high-speed SSDs, in order to move the data without
any bottleneck constraints by the chipset.

Chipset lanes are used for onboard USB, other M.2 and PCIe slots and SATA.
The chipset itself transfers data to the processor via a dedicated
4-lane PCIe bus.
The result is that devices connected via PCIe lanes to the chipset
have a cap on their maximum bandwidth, which is why processor lanes
are used for the faster devices.

For more information, see the article
[Guide to PCIe Lanes: How many do you need for your workload?](https://www.cgdirector.com/guide-to-pcie-lanes/)

Comment: So , if i go with a processor which has less than 16 lanes then i will not get maximum potential of graphics card because x16 pcie lanes is directly connected to processor so if processor has 14 lanes then graphics card will bottleneck. Am i right

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The processor has 20 lanes available for devices to be directly connected to the CPU.

The processor then has a separate high bandwidth link to the motherboard chipset and hanging off the chipset are the other 14 lanes and all the other peripherals.

As a result the CPU can generally handle a 4x NVMe device at the same time as either 1 GPU at x16 or 2 GPUs at x8 each.

Comment: How would i know that lanes which is connected to cpu is attached to which interface 1x16 or 2 x8 if there are 3 interface present 1 x16 and 2 x8

Comment: @YashRaj You look at your motherboard specifications. In your case https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-B760M-E-DDR4/Specification states that you have a 1 x16 port coming from the CPU and then a 1 x1 PCIe slot coming from the chipset. You also have an x4 m.2 coming from the chipset, so the extra 4 lanes from the CPU are left unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, the CPU and PCH/platform chipset communicate through the equivalent of PCIe Gen4 x4 - this link is actually called DMI and is not counted as part of your PCIe lanes. So, 20 PCIe lanes are available - 4 lanes to your M.2 slot (M2_1), and 16 lanes for the PCIe x16 slot (PCI_E1). The PCH provides a x1 gen3 slot (PCI_E2) as well as connects the rest of your integrated devices. Note that if you installed a SATA SSD into M2_1 it would route through the SATA controller in the PCH and not through the CPU, likely through a mux.

In general, the exact configuration of lanes and how they're available is determined by the capabilities of the CPU, the capability of the platform chipset, and the exact motherboard implementation. You'll need to look up all three to have a clear picture.

Keep in mind that PCIe lanes that are offered through the PCH/chipset aren't as fast due to sharing the DMI with other devices to connect to the CPU.